# centos and fontpackages-filesystem

Tags: installation, centos, yum, rpm

How do I go about installing fontpackages-filesystem onto centos?

Getting the error:
`Missing Dependency: fontpackages-filesystem >= 1.13 is needed by package liberation-fonts-common-1.05.1.20090721-4_1.noarch (atrpms)`

Is this not designed for centos?

Getting the error trying to run `yum groupinstall "X Window System" "KDE (K Desktop Environment)"`

any help would be great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might have the an EPEL yum repository in your yum configuration. For Fedora and Redhat systems, that is where the fontpackages-filesystem package is found. The Centos wiki webpage, http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories, warns that "It should also be noted that, while EPEL may not overwrite distro packages, it may have conflicts with the CentOS extras repo which is enabled by default."